# Confusion about chiral anomaly (Fujikawa's method)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, path-integral, quantum-anomalies, chirality

I am reading Fujikawa's method for calculating chiral anomaly, see [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujikawa_method).

The method can be described as follows.
It starts with the path integral
\begin{equation}
Z=\int\mathcal{D}\psi\mathcal{D}\bar{\psi}e^{i\int \mathcal{L}}.
\end{equation}
First we calculate the shift of Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}(\psi,\partial \psi)$ due to the local chiral transformation
\begin{equation}
\psi'=e^{i\alpha(x)\gamma^5}\psi.
\end{equation}
we get
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}(\psi',\partial \psi')=\mathcal{L}(\psi,\partial \psi)+\alpha \partial_{\mu}(\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^5\psi).
\end{equation}
On the other hand, we also calculate the path integral measure due to above chiral transformation, we have
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{D}\psi'\mathcal{D}\bar{\psi}'=\mathcal{D}\psi\mathcal{D}\bar{\psi}e^{2i\int \alpha(x)A(x)}.
\end{equation}
We require $Z$ should be invariant under local chiral transformation, then we have
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\mu}(\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^5\psi)=-2A(x).
\end{equation}

**Now here is my confusion**: why do we require $Z$ is invariant under local transformation $\psi'=e^{i\alpha(x)\gamma^5}\psi$? If we don't, then there is no reason to expect $\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^5\psi$ to be conserved. (It is called "anomaly" because we expect it is conserved but it is not.)

Comment: Why should an integral depend on what you call its dummy variables of integration?